# First 0x7E00 bytes on USB flash drive have become invisible

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, mbr

I have somehow managed to make the first 0x7E00 bytes (63 sectors) of my USB flash drive invisible to every program in Windows XP. I have tried about 15 different disk editors and tried a lot of MBR repair options and whatnot, but all seem to believe the disk starts 0x7E00 bytes later than it really does. The formatting options in XP, whether to format it as FAT or NTFS, work "just fine" and I can even add files on it but there's still the problem of the invisible sectors (Windows really pretends that the disk starts there). HxD hex editor shows 0x7E00 bytes less than it used to. CreateFile API with \.\PhysicalDriveX does the same. I tried installing bootable Linux with 3 different installers and all install it at the wrong spot (I know it is wrong because if I try to boot from it, it does not boot into Linux but the old MBR which contains garbage code). Messing with BIOS options does nothing. Trying "Rufus" formatting options FAT and NTFS format it just as wrong as everything else, but exFAT comes up with an "Undetermined error while formatting" and the log says there are 63 hidden sectors. How do I zero or otherwise overwrite these 63 sectors, or make them visible again?

Answer (score 0):

I have one option in mind.

create a binary file with 512 0's let's suppose it is X.bin

now copy the file to first 63 sector using dd

`sudo dd if=/home/user/X.bin of=/dev/sdc bs=512 count=63`

Here /dev/sdc is your pendrive.

If you don't understand the process of creating the binary file , please comment.